# Mobile browsers ignoring Access-Control-Max-Age

Tags: nginx, cors, jquery-file-upload

I'm doing some cross domain chunked uploads with CORS, on a really super slow connection (low signal HSPA or 3G) i find that the client is re-requesting the OPTIONS for almost every POST (on a 1-2 minute interval). I have already set a 10 minute preflight approval set (add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 600;) and i have confirmed with inspector that the mobile client is receiving this header.  Is there some other header that i need to add to make the client not repeatedly make OPTIONS requests?

I have read the other threads but none of them provide any solution to my issue:

[Is Chrome ignoring Control-Cache: max-age?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245767/is-chrome-ignoring-control-cache-max-age)

[CORS Access-Control-Max-Age is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543719/cors-access-control-max-age-is-ignored)

All of them say that the browser *should* accept a 10 minute pre flight cache if i set that header, but this is not what i am experiencing at all.  And those repeated requests for OPTIONS is only making my slow users experience worse by slowing down the upload speed even further.

I have cross posted this issue to the google chrome issue tracker here:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=131368#c10  with some screenshots from the inspector.